# How to use regular expression with a property value in testcomplete

Tags: vbscript, testcomplete

I'm from UFT background. I've just started using testcomplete yesterday. My manager told me to evaluate this tool.

I've come to a place where I have to use regular expression with a property value. Here's the code:

```
Aliases.HX01W00W.Window("IEFWINDOW", "Outbound Service - 0092020203030303  1  2", 1).Window("IEFWINDOW", "Service", 1).Window("Edit", "NY", 149)
```

This line of code works perfectly. I can set a value in the edit box. I can also get a property value from this object. However, if you can see, this part of the code always changes: `Window("IEFWINDOW", "Outbound Service - 0092020203030303  1  2", 1)`.

Only, the word `Service` doesn't change.
I've tried changing that piece of code to:

`Window("IEFWINDOW", ".*Service.*", 1)`

`Window("IEFWINDOW", "*Service*", 1)`

In UFT this line: `Window("text:=.*Service.*")`identifies the window.

How can I use regular expression on this part of the code so I can interact with this object?

If someone can provide similar piece of code that actually works would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards should work for you:

```
Window("IEFWINDOW", "*Service*", 1)
```

Anyway, you can use regular expressions as well:

```
Aliases.HX01W00W.FindChild(Array("WndClass", "WndCaption"), Array("IEFWINDOW", "regexp:.*Service.*"))
```

More information can be found in the [Using Regular Expressions in Scripts](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/scripting/regular-expressions.html) help topic.